# Prove the monotonicity of $\operatorname{arg} f $

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem: $\gamma=\{|f| = c\}$ is a smooth Jordan curve, and $f$ is holomorphic in the region $D$ with boundary $\gamma$, prove that (a) $\operatorname{arg} f$ is monotone when $z$ goes through $\gamma$, (b)$f$ has one more zero than $f'$ in D.

My train of thought is that supposing $f = u + \mathrm{i} v$ and $\operatorname{arg} f = \arctan \frac{v}{u}$, we have $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(\operatorname{arg} f)' = \frac{(uv)'}{u^2+v^2}$, but I can't proceed.

There's a hint that the problem can be solved based on Cauchy-Riemann equation's alternertive:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial n},\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}
$$
where $n$ and $s$ are two direction s.t. $s = n\mathrm{i}$, and the argument principle.